# Using az storage command with azurite

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I'm trying to create a container using the command line provided in azurite readme and the result is :

> Unable to obtain data client. Check your connection parameters.

I'm running the docker version of azurite, is there something to do specifically when using the az command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to bash instead of cmd make it work.